# when i use a class within a class how can i call a upon attributes from the original class

Tags: python, class, oop

When calling upon classes within other classes, how do i call upon attributes in the nested path that are in the class that called it

the example below is an attempt of mine to solve this by myself. of course this results in an error claiming that 'example' isnt defined, but i thought i would show it to make it clear what im trying to do

```
class CamelCase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 'foo'
        self.variable2  = CamelCase_2()


class CamelCase_2:
    def __init__(self):
        return example.variable        #this is the part i want to be able to do properly. 
                                       #using the attribute attribute 'variable' within CamelCase_2


example = CamelCase()
print(foo.variable2)
```

please note that the above is a simplification of what im trying to do. assume that im actually trying to use the function upper() on example.variable within CameCase2

Comment: Class names are by convention `CamelCase`

Comment: my bad im still new to this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You may want to read up a bit more on OOP because this construction you have doesn't make sense: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

Comment: I also didn't literally mean you needed to name your classes `CamelCase`. I meant that instead of `foo_one` and `foo_two` they should be in camel case, which means `FooOne` and `FooTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

`CamelCase` needs to pass itself to `CamelCase_2`.

```
class CamelCase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 'foo'
        self.variable2  = CamelCase_2(self)


class CamelCase_2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.camelcase = parent
```

Then other methods in `CamelCase_2` can refer to `self.camelcase` to access the object that created it.